# What exact sequence of control characters ends a comment in C++?

Tags: c++, ascii, comments, newline, translation

The book *A Tour of C++* states that

> The double slash, //, begins a comment that extends to the end of the line.

What exact sequence of control characters constitutes the "end of line".

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) wikipedia article, there are four different ways to represent a new line in ASCII.
These are the following sequences:
LF
CR
LF CR
CR LF

Will all of these work to separate the end of a comment from the beginning of the next line of code?

Comment: Yes...........*

Comment: It's whatever is considered a new line character for your implementation: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.comment#1.sentence-3

Comment: @NathanOliver add some source that shows that newlines are indeed implementation-dependent, and this is an answer

Comment: It is implementation-dependent: "Physical source file characters are mapped, [in an implementation-defined manner](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.phases#1.1), to the translation character set ([lex.charset]) (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators)."

Comment: *there are four different ways to represent a new line in ASCII.* Who says the source code is in ASCII? If your editor shows a line break, that's probably where the comment ends on your system.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ 14 Standard (2.2 Phases of translation)

> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
> the following phases.
>
> 1. Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source  character set
>    (**introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators**) if
>    necessary.

So the end of a line is indicated by the new line character `'\n'`.

Comment: new-line *characters*, emphasis on the plural.  So a line ending could be '\r' or "\r\n" or 0x0a.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In C++ the new line character is '\n'.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Any of these should work. CR LF (Windows) and LF (Unix-related) are the most commonly used these days, but the other two have been used historically.

Comment: Correction: *Yes. Any of these should work **on a system that recognizes them as the end of a line***. Usually only one line ending is recognized on a system and your answer suggests that all the listed line endings will work everywhere.